# Alternate installer for MySQL v5.5?

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I tried to install MySQL v5.5 on my PC, but it [won't install on my machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/214435/error-1067-the-process-terminated-unexpectedly-when-trying-to-install-mysql-on).

Is there another installer that contains MySQL v5.5 that I can try, preferably not the official one from http://www.mysql.com/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using PostgreSQL. I also managed to get MySQL working (after a huge amount of problems with it - the MySQL developers obviously never tested it much on Windows as it barely works).